# Need help creating a weekly refresh for my google form responses

Tags: date, google-apps-script

I am not a programmer and I am looking for guidance regarding a google form. I am simply looking to delete the responses to my google form every week (sunday @ midnight). Here is some pseudo-code to help clarify my question.

```
function myFunction() {

var form = FormApp.getActiveForm();
var formResponses = form.getResponses();
var dayofweek = getthedate();

if(dayofweek == SUNDAY AT 12:00AM PST){
   form.deleteAllResponses();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

You can put this in the script editor for the form.  You need to run the createTrigger just once.  You can check that it was creating by going to Edit/Get Project Triggers.

```
function delFormResponses() {
  var form=FormApp.getActiveForm();
  form.deleteAllResponses()
}

function createTrigger() {
  var form=FormApp.getActiveForm();
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('delFormResponses').timeBased().onWeekDay(ScriptApp.WeekDay.SUNDAY).atHour(0).create();
}
```